# How to random change the positions of keyboard buttons?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have to write the text to Edittext to match the string, but i need to change the randomly change the position of keyboard buttons. How to do it i searched it but found nothing. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to change the layout of the keyboard buttons randomly? Try writing your own keyboard app.

Comment: I have to make a numeric keyboard where number comes at random position every times it open , if you have got any solution of your problem then please suggest me. Thanks in advance